# Как разместить проект на Angular на GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, angular, github-pages

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разместить проект на Angular на GitHub Pages, чтобы отображалась верстка со стилями.

Ссылка на репозиторий, для которого хочу создать GitHub страницу: https://github.com/monsara/angular-contacts

До этого использовал сборщик Gulp и страницы всегда отображались на GitHub Pages.
Например это ссылка на исходные файлы страницы https://github.com/monsara/witcher

А это ссылка на GitHub Pages с отображением вестки и стилей https://monsara.github.io/witcher/

Возможно для этого нужно исключить папку dist из файла .gitignore, и запушить проект с папкой dist?

Comment: http://google.com/?q=angular%20static%20site%20generator -> "Мне повезёт!"

Comment: https://scully.io/